# Throw three dice such that at least two $3$'s shows up with $0.25$ probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, binomial-distribution, dice

> We consider three fair dice which are thrown simultanously. In other words, one repetition of the experiment means that we have thrown three dice.
>
> Use Chebyshev inequality $P(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|\geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}$, where $\epsilon>0$, to find the minimum number of repetitions of the experiment such that the probability of getting at least two $3$'s is $0.25$ or more. We can assume that each repitition is independent from others.

---

I know that this question seems odd because it is easy to do it without Chebyshev inequality. However, our professor wants us to apply Chebyshev inequality.

---

**My approach:**

Let be $X_i$ a random variable with $1\leq i\leq n$, such that $X_i=1$, if at least two $3$'s show up and otherwise $X_i=0$. It is easy to see that $P(X_i=1)=\frac{2}{27}$ and $P(X_i=0)=\frac{25}{27}$. Then, we know $Y:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ obeys a Binomial distribution and $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\frac{2n}{27}$ and $\mathbb{V}(Y)=\frac{50n}{27^2}$. To answer the question we must find a $n$ such that $P(Y\geq 1)$.

In order to apply Chebyshev inequality we have to do some tricky manipulations and assume that $n$ is large enough such that $\mathbb{E}(Y)-1=\frac{2n}{27}-1>0$.

\begin{align*}
&1.) ~P(Y\geq 1)\geq 0.25\iff P(Y<1)\leq 0.75\\
&~\\
&2.)~P(Y<1)=P(Y-\mathbb{E}(Y)\leq 1-\mathbb{E}(Y))=P(\mathbb{E}(Y)-Y\geq \mathbb{E}(Y)-1)\\
&\leq P(|\mathbb{E}(Y)-Y|\geq \mathbb{E}(Y)-1)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(Y)}{(\mathbb{E}(Y)-1)^2}\\
&\implies P(Y<1)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(Y)}{(\mathbb{E}(Y)-1)^2}=\frac{\frac{50n}{27^2}}{\left(\frac{2n}{27}-1\right)^2}.
\end{align*}

In equation 2.) I have used the subset property and applied Chebyshev inequality. Long story short, we are looking for a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{\frac{50n}{27^2}}{\left(\frac{2n}{27}-1\right)^2}\leq 0.75$. After some manipulations of the inequality we see that $n\geq 39$.

---

My tutor deducted almost $50$% of the points just mentioning that I can't do it this way and it is not clear if the $n$ I found is truely the smallest number of repitition if we use Chebyshev inequality. To be honest I don't know what she meant and I don't see any mistakes. Maybe someone else can explain to me what is wrong with my solution.

Comment: This is very far off...the probability that you'll get at least two $3's$ is $p\approx .074$ so you want the least $n$ such that $1-(1-p)^n<.25$ ...$n=18$ is right there.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Taking $n=18$ gives you a $75\%$ chance of seeing the event, you only asked for a $25\%$ chance.  That's just $n=4$.

Comment: @lulu, I know that this approach is overcomplicating things but as I mentioned we must solve it by applying Chebyshev inequality. We are explicitely told not to solve it as you suggested.

Comment: Well, I don't understand.  Chebyshev is a very blunt instrument.  Its beauty is that it holds for general distributions.  Its weakness is that it throws away most properties of whatever explicit distribution you have.  I don't see how you can use it to find the minimal $n$...

Comment: Perhaps the point is to look at the number of successes you have in $n$ trials. That's some distribution around $p\times n$ and you just want to get the probability that you end up less than $.5$ (approximating with something continuous).

Comment: Just using the normal approximation to that works pretty well...I got $n=3$ which isn't that far off.  I still don't see how, even in principle, one can be sure of finding the exact min this way.  All these things are approximations and we've lost a lot of information.

Comment: "My tutor deducted almost 50% of the points just mentioning that I can't do it this way and it is not clear if the n I found is truely the smallest number of repitition if we use Chebyshev inequality" well of course not, Chebyshev inequality just provides *an* upper bound, it's usually not a very good one, let alone the *best* one. I think the tutor failed to understand that this is an exercise in applying CI not in finding the optimal n

Comment: Simply put, you arrived at the correct answer using the instructed method so you are right and tutor is wrong

Comment: @Alborz, if you tinker around with the $\epsilon$ you find that $P(|Y-\mathbb{E}(Y)|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(Y)}{\epsilon^2}$ leads to $ P(|Y-\frac{2n}{27}(Y)|>1.5)\leq\frac{\frac{50n}{27^2}}{2.25}\overset{???}{\leq}0.75$. Then, $n\geq 21$ also delivers the desired result. So I guess there must be a different approach by using CI. But I have to admit that this is a really strange and confusing problem. I don't quite understand how this fits in the whole context of understanding the CI!?!?